# What is an architecture?

Tags: architecture

I've read many times the terms:

- cpu architecture
- hardware architecture
- software architecture
- computer architecture

And so I thought an architecture describes the structure (layout,interface, position,functionality,...) of something.
Am I right, or do I have to distinguish in those cases!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like landscape architectures describe the physical elements and "style" of a building and piece of land (such as "[modern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_architecture)", "[craftsman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Craftsman)", "[tudor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tudor_architecture)", etc.), so too do all of the electronic architectures:

- [CPU Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture) is how a series of CPUs work. Even though it is a separate entity, CPU's are so complex today that the rest of the computer is typically designed around them.
- [Hardware Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_architecture) is how some particular piece or group of hardware works. There are many types, and in the case of computers, must match the rest of the components to work properly.
- [Software Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture) is how a particular piece or group of software works, or the reasoning for choosing certain elements of software design over other elements. (I.e., reliability over speed, etc.)
- Computer Architecture is closely linked to CPU and Hardware Architecture (they must be the same type for it to work), and is the particular style or method used to form the computing device. So an Intel x86 CPU only works with Intel x86 compatible hardware, and using Intel x86-compatible software.

Note that some software compilers can target multiple "platforms" or architectures. [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) for example, the GNU C Compiler, can output binary images (executable code) for about 21 modern [architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection), with at least double-that available for lesser-known ones, and over two dozen additional ones not included with GCC.

Architectures exist because these devices are so complex. If there were no "rules" about how these things worked, then it would be hopeless to try connecting anything. Architectures also exist for education and manufacturability reasons, so that new designers can get up-to-speed in design, and manufacturers can create the designs with more than a guess as to whether it will work or not.